# Has problems after @PathVariable parameter value containing the '#' character,with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

- am using spring mvc & spring boot
- i have developed **demopro-dispatcher-servlet.xml** and 
  sample code is

  ```
  <mvc:interceptor>
      <mvc:mapping path="/login/**" />
      <ref bean="loginInterceptor" />
  </mvc:interceptor>
  <bean id="loginInterceptor" class="com.demo.interceptor.LoginInterceptor" />
  ```
- My **LoginInterceptor** sample code is

  ```
  private static String[] SERVLET_PATHS = {
    "/login/email/password"
  .. }
  ```
- My **LoginController** sample code is

  ```
  @Controller
  @RequestMapping("login")
  public class LoginController{
   ......
   @RequestMapping("/email/password/{email:.+}/{password:.+}")
  @Transactional
  public @ResponseBody void authenticationForLogin(@PathVariable String email, @PathVariable String password, HttpServletRequest request,
          HttpServletResponse response) {
  //i tried this code
   /*
   String restOfTheUrl1 = (String) request.getAttribute(
              HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE);
      logger.debug("Here password is : "+password+" : "+restOfTheUrl1);
   */

    logger.debug("Here password is : "+password);
     //Its print demo!@ but input is demo!@#$%^
  ```
- My Request URL : "**http:localhost:8080/demopro/login/email/password/{email}/{password}**"
- Am calling URL from post man : "**http:localhost:8080/demopro/login/email/password/acecd@gmail.com/demo!@#$%^**"
- password printing like **demo!@**
- **help on this save my days**, i want to changes only server side..
- thank you in advance..

Comment: Your client should be URL escaping the path before passing it to the server. If there is no way you can change the client you'll have to map your controller to a shorter root (i.e. `/email/password/`) and do the parsing yourself.

Comment: @teppic - thank you for quick replay, please can you give sample how to parsing, means URL parsing? already i have tried this but am not getting full URL **String restOfTheUrl1 = (String) request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE);**

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read your question closely enough. Your problem is caused by the unescaped `#` (anchor delimiter). The browser won't pass the anchor to your server. You will have to fix the client.

Comment: do not pass the login credentials via URL, use HTTP POST request

Answer (score 0):

As you are passing sensitive data like email and password  it would be recommended to use  url  encoding/decoding here.You will need to pass the encoded url from UI and then  in the controller you can decode the it as

```
String result = URLDecoder.decode(url , "UTF-8");
```